# Controlling the Axis of a NumPy Histogram

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, histogram

I have a sorted, 1D NumPy array which contains 156k integers that range from 263,168 to 24,064,000. I don't know how the items in the array are distributed so I am trying to plot the data as a histogram.

I've tried setting different values for the `bins` parameter but I still end up with a plot that doesn't allow me to see the distribution.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

np_ary = # integer array of data
print(np_ary)
plt.hist(np_ary, bins='auto')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: You probably have some outliers in your data. You can pass a `list` or `np.array`  of bin edges to the `bins` argument to manual set the bins. Alternatively you can set a range e.g. `range=(0, 5e6)`

Comment: Start with manual queries then. How many values of 1000000 do you have (`np.count_nonzero(np_ray>1000000)`)?